# How to secure env variables in gcp app engine app.yaml deployment file?

Tags: google-app-engine

by the [app.yaml configuration files documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref), its allows env variables like:

```yaml
runtime: nodejs16 # or another supported version

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: "example-gcs-bucket"
  DB_PASSWORD: "my_secret_pw"
```

However some of those variables may contain sensitive data like `DB_PASSWORD`.

The deployment yaml file is in the repository and the CI pipeline reffers it to deploy to the GCP App Engine service.

How can i secure the those variable value and prevent that anyone with repository acesses be able to see them?

Answer (score 2):

Storing db credentials in `app.yaml` file is not ideal.
A better and more secure approach that you can consider is to use [Cloud KMS](https://cloud.google.com/security-key-management):

- Use a service account with encyrpt and decrypt permission (role) to encyrpt the credentials (secrets) file.
- Upload the encrypted credential file to Cloud Storage.
- Fetch the encrypted credential from GCS, decrypt and parse it at runtime in your application code

There is the [How-to: Storing secrets](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypting-application-data) that shows how to use Cloud KMS to store secrets in Cloud Storage.